# WordPress - enable or disable custom post typesfrom dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm creating a wordpress plugin. The plugin will register some custom routes in the REST api and some custom post types. Is possible to add a way to let the user enable or disable CPT and eventually create new CPT?

**EXAMPLE**

```php
    public function create_new_cpt( WP_REST_Request $request )
    {
        $args = $request->get_param('newCptDetails');

        $cpt = register_post_type( 
            $args['name'], 
            [
                'label' => $args['label'],
                'description' => $args['desc'],
                'show_ui' => true,
                'show_in_menu' => true,
                'show_in_rest' => true
            ]
        );

            add_option( 'cpt_name', $args['name'] );
            add_option( 'cpt_label', $args['label'] );
            add_option( 'description', $args['desc'] );
            return $cpt;

    }
```

Comment: Yes, you’d just create your interface, persist it somewhere like wp_options, and use that as a reference when registering your CPTs.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I know I can use `add_option()` and use `update_option()` on a rest endpoint, my doubt is about registration of new CPT and activation and deactivation of the new CPT. I will need to save all the needed params into the `wp_options` table?

Comment: The REST endpoint doesn't really matter to the problem, except that it updates the options. You just need code that boots with WordPress, probably in the `init` hook, that reads the option key and calls `register_post_type` on the items. Part of the data in the option should be a disabled/enabled key.

Comment: I'm calling the `register_post_type` when the user submit the form, the problem is that if I want to add new CPT there is no way to call the `init` hook from inside a callback method

Comment: The CPT will not exist for that very specific REST call, that call will only be a place to register CPTs for all future requests

Comment: not sure to understand, how I can solve the problem of adding the CPT on demand?

Comment: Just to be 100% clear because maybe I’m misunderstanding you, registering a CPT is not a one-time event. You don’t “register” it and WordPress remembers that until you “unregister” it some day in the future. Your code will register the CPT _every time_ WordPress loads for _every request_. So your REST code will update options, and your other code, which is already running for every request, will fetch the same option key and register whatever it finds in there.